# How far ahead is The Great British Bakeoff filmed?

Tags: production, the-great-british-bakeoff

There has been some controversy over the last week about about a [Baked Alaska disaster](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/28965236) where one of the contestants accidentally removed another's ice cream from the freezer. Following this he decided not to present his dessert to the judges which cost him his place in the competition.

I'm very interested in the reaction which this has generated in response. There seem to be lots of discussions about removing Diana (who removed the ice cream) and reinstating Iain (who left). However it's my understanding that the series was filmed several weeks ago.

Here are a few examples (quote from the linked article)

> There were calls for Diana Beard, who at 69 is the show's oldest
>   contestant, to be told off, disqualified and even arrested.

This makes it sound like the competition is currently going on and that the producers could actually disqualify her. However in a statement from the BBC they commented that

> Diana will not appear in the rest of the series as she fell ill ahead
>   of filming episode five earlier this year.

This sounds to me like the show was filmed months ago.

When exactly are the Bakeoff (and indeed other shows like it) are filmed in relation to when they are broadcast? Are they filmed in advance and broadcast at a later date or are they filmed and shown week by week?

Comment: How is this off topic? How is this *Trivia*? It's asking whether a show is broadcast live(-ish) or whether or not the campaign to have a contestant disqualified was legitimate; inferring it could have been part of an astro-turf marketing strategy for the shows creators... this is an interesting answer that's incredibly relevant to [an ongoing 'scandal](http://www.studentbeans.com/mag/en/news/16-very-british-reactions-to-the-bake-off-scandal)' and fits here perfectly, can some of the down-voters explain themselves?

Comment: Further to this, there are now calls of intimidation being leveled against the BBC by contestants involved, claiming they [manipulated and scapegoated certain individuals.](http://www.dailyrecord.co.uk/entertainment/tv-radio/bake-offs-diana-beard-accuses-4122352) This is not only on-topic, it's also pertinent to discussions here and very interesting, and will no doubt be unfolding in the weeks to come: not many people have a platform like ours to investigate it, its such a shame we've closed this down...

Comment: Let's discuss this on Meta - http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/is-the-great-british-bakeoff-question-off-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**Bake Off insiders reveal what really goes on inside the tent**](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2014-08-06/bake-off-insiders-reveal-what-really-goes-on-inside-the-tent):

> In the first year the show moved from place to place every week. **This year (2014) the tent was pitched in April at [Welford Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welford_Park) in Berkshire for ten weeks.**
>
> *"We try to record at weekends, because so many of our contestants have day jobs. They arrive, go into the tent, and bake for Mary and Paul. That’s it."* says executive producer [Anna Beattie](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1511074/).
>
> **Each episode is filmed over two days.**
>
> **“We record the entire series before transmission,”** says Beattie. “Of course, we then have to keep the winner a secret until the series ends. It is a risk, because it relies on everyone involved playing ball, but we trust people not to spoil it.”

(Note that the 2014 series was filmed starting in April, according to the above quote;  it began airing in August 2014.)

Answer (score 0):

Filming finished in June 2014. Not sure when it started.

Comment: @MattD Does it not? It seems it does (albeit completely unproved).

Comment: @MattD - in my opinion it is an answer, just with no references, or indicating any detail about what that date means for the question.

Comment: Yeah, should have put more concrete info in there, and should have done it as a comment instead... Friend worked on the production but no definite info.